# Reading large compressed files

Tags: python, gzip

This might be a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer to this or why it is not working on this specific case.

I want to read large files, they can be compressed or not. I used `contextlib` to write a `contextmanager` function to handle this. Then using the `with` statement I read the files in the main script.

My problem here is that the script uses a lot of memory then gets killed (testing using a compressed file). What am I doing wrong? Should I approach this differently?

```
def process_vcf(location):
    logging.info('Processing vcf')
    logging.debug(location)
    with read_compressed_or_not(location) as vcf:
        for line in vcf.readlines():
            if line.startswith('#'):
                logging.debug(line)

@contextmanager
def read_compressed_or_not(location):
    if location.endswith('.gz'):
        try: 
            file = gzip.open(location)
            yield file
        finally:
            file.close()
    else:
        try: 
            file = open(location, 'r')
            yield file
        finally:
            file.close()
```

Comment: It's because your `readlines()` call is reading the *entire file into memory*. Just process it a line at a time as shown in @Tim Roberts' answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `for line in vcf.readlines()`, you can do:

```
line = vcf.readline()
while line:
    # Do stuff
    line = vcf.readline()
```

This will only load one single line into memory at once

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem, I will accept in a few minutes when I can.

Comment: You don't need an unintuitive `while` loop for this.  Making a minor change to the for loop will do the same thing much more readably:  `for line in vcf:`

Comment: @TimRoberts It depends on what you are doing in the loop, this `while` loop implementation is way more versatile because you can read a different number of lines each iteration.

Comment: Which is, of course, not what he needs to do.  Duplicating the `readline` makes it more confusing for the reader.

Comment: @TimRoberts Make your own answer then

Comment: I was convinced that by using for line in readlines() it was already loading one line at a time. I am not used to writing memory efficient. It does now make a lot more sense what was wrong. And it was not even related to it being compressed or not.

Comment: `.readlines()` loads all of the lines into a list. using `for line in file` will generate each line on the fly, so it uses much less memory for large files.

Answer (score 3):

The lowest impact solution is just to skip the use of the `readlines` function.  `readlines` returns a list containing every line in the file, so it does have the entire file in memory.  Using the filename by itself reads one line at a time using a generator, so it doesn't have to have the whole file in memory.

```
    with read_compressed_or_not(location) as vcf:
        for line in vcf:
            if line.startswith('#'):
                logging.debug(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

The file opening function is the main difference between reading a gzip file and a non-gzip file. So one can dynamically assign the opener and then read the file. Then there is no need for a custom context manager.

```py
import gzip

open_fn = gzip.open if location.endswith(".gz") else open
with open_fn(location, mode="rt") as vcf:
    for line in vcf:
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this, made my code better.